# How to check which file is older

Tags: files-and-directories

Is there a command in Mathematica to check the date when a file was last modified? Suppose I have two notebooks: `File1.nb` and `File2.nb`, I need a way to find out which notebook is older. If no such command exists is there a way to do this in *Mathematica* regardless of the operating system we are working on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for [`FileDate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FileDate.html).

Comment: lol, I feel dumb now. I had been looking all over google for it but forgot to put it in the documentation center. What is more embarrassing, is that the tag for the question is all I had to put in the documentation center to find the answer (It took me a while to think of the tag too).

Comment: @jmlopez I started my search with `FileNames` which had a link to `File Operations`, and under _File Properties_ was `FileDate`.

Answer (score 12):

Here are some commands I ran on my machine to generate a few files, and give them some history:

```
touch foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4
touch foo3
cat foo2
```

Here are the files:

```
files = FileNames["foo*"]

(*
==> {"foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4"}
*)
```

The most recently changed file:

```
SortBy[files, FileDate] // Last

(*
==> "foo3"
*)
```

The newest file:

```
SortBy[files, FileDate[#, "Creation"] &] // Last

(*
==> "foo4"
*)
```

The most recent file that was looked at:

```
SortBy[files, FileDate[#, "Access"] &] // Last

(*
==> "foo2"
*)
```

Comment: What my answer should have looked like, +1.

Comment: @rcollyer yet another example of why we need collaborative answers.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I think the collaborative answers should be implemented. Is someone working on this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard they do exist, in a way: community-wiki. But, not in the sense your thinking of.

Comment: @jmlopez as far as I know: not at this time.  I am hoping to built interest in this possible feature, at which time the devs may consider it.