# Order imported files by their alteration date

Tags: import, files-and-directories, sorting

Probably a very easy question, but I could not find the answer, so it would be very nice if you can help me:

Let us say I have 10 files, all with the extension `.dat`. Using

```
data = Import[#, "Table"] & /@ FileNames["*.dat"];
```

I can import all .dat files in a folder.

However, I want *Mathematica* to order these .dat files by their alteration date just like I can do it under Windows with a right click > Sort by > alteration date. I want *Mathematica* to import the files in exactly this order. How might I do this?

Comment: Closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5765/131

Answer (score 7):

```
dateOrdered = ((names = FileNames["*.dat"])[[Ordering[ FileDate[#, "Modification"] & /@ names]]]);

data = Import[#, "Table"] & /@ dateOrdered;
```

This will import with oldest modification date first, most recent last.